# Convergence in probability and distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

suppose that $x_n$ $\to$ x in distribution and $y_n$ $\to$ 0 in probability as n $\to$ $\infty$

prove that $x_n +y_n$ $\to$ x in distribution and $x_n y_n$ $\to$ 0 in distribution as n $\to$ $\infty$

how I can show that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Lemma 3.3.2, p. 70 (Slutsky's Lemma) for the first part and Theorem 3.3.3, p. 71 (extension of Slutsky's Lemma) for the second part in the following notes: http://www.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/vidsand12.pdf

Comment: what about part 2 can i find easiest prove other than !!